# How to draw a simple line without using Interface Builder?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I'm a beginner. I just want to draw a simple line without using IB .
code I used is

lineViewController.m

```
-(id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,440)];
        myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        mView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)];

        self.view = myView;
        [myView addSubView:mView];          
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    line = [[MyView alloc]init];
    [line setNeedsDisplay];         
}
```

MyView.m

```
#import "MyView.h"

@implementation MyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat red[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, red);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 150.0f, 200.0f);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 5.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 50,300);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 260,300);
    CGContextClosePath(c);
}
```

But I'm not able to draw. Can you please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you have forgotten `CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();`

Comment: Sorry, I forgotten to enter here.but I placed this in my coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in viewWillAppear doesn't do anything because line is never added to the view hierarchy.  MyView drawRect is never called because of the above and "myView" is allocated as a UIView instead of a MyView.   Try changing the alloc in the view controller init.

```
myView = [[MyView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,440)];
```

Also the code will leak as written.  Look into retain & release memory management.